# Rough printing surface

Tags: creality-ender-3, print-quality, extrusion

I'm new to 3d printing, printing with Creality Ender-3 S1 Pro. I had printed out some downloaded complicated parts and some simple parts of my own, and I was really impressed with surface finish.

Now I'm trying to print a lampshade from silk PLA.

[image: Lampshade design]

First tried to print a sample where the profile of each element is half moon. But with 2 x 2 walls and space in between it would not let light through. But the finish was great! Then tried to make a loft where the profile is a 'moon skin', 0.8 mm. The loft turned out to be of variable thickness, but mostly 2 walls. Perfect thickness but the quality is far from perfect. 0.2mm layer height, 0.4mm line width, 200 deg C.

[image: Result #1]

[image: Result #2]

[image]

Tried a slice of a lampshade from Thingiverse, and it's opposite from smooth... Any advice very much appreciated. I'm at the bottom of that steep learning curve.

It's 200 °C, Ziro PLA Silk filament.

Also, I chose the same sample to print for the second time by mistake. It was exactly same lines that were under-extruded.

Comment: In future, please [edit] and add any additional info to the question itself and *not* in the the comments. I have done it for you this time.  Thanks.